# Are there any plans for C++14 or later for standardized backtrace and other debugging utilities?

Tags: c++, debugging, standards

Are there any plans for standardized backtrace and other debugging utilities to be added to C++14 (or above), or will it continue to be a functionality added by OS or compiler?

Comment: I'd say that's out of the scope of the C++ standard. It would be great if standards like that were language independent.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that.  However, I've written some platform independent (well, Windows & Linux) backtraces in the past.  It's very specific to a compiler and OS combination.  I think you if do a little research, you can write one yourself (maybe even submit it to boost).

Comment: Yes you can! Yet to get a backtrace any time you need it for a thread you need (not only for current\crashing one) would be so much better!

Comment: ew a bounty.  So I guess you want someone to say yes.  Since you refuse to accept no for the answer..  Believe what you want then.

Comment: No backtrace, but [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3753.pdf) is probably the closest thing to what you mean by "other debugging utilities"

Answer (score 12):

No.  There are no plans.

For one the standard does not specify how function calls are to be made.  And in all actuality this is dependent upon the hardware.  You probably dont know this but there is hardware out there that does not push return addresses onto a stack.  Some of them use dynamic jmp instructions, and others use return queues to keep track of return addressees.

The stack trace which you're referring to is possible on a, albeit large, subset of processors, but since C and C++ was intended to run on as many processors as possible it will not, can not, define a standard way of performing a back trace which would dictate how hardware should be manufactured.

Comment: The logic is somewhat faulty. A "stack backtrace" specified by the standard wouldn't need to assume a physical stack. Your "return queue" can be translated into a list of calling functions using the same mechanisms. This is in fact easier, as the whole contents of th return address queue are addresses inside functions. An x86 stack contains these return addresses but also random other data, so locating the return address in each stack frame is non-trivial.

Comment: and when functions are inlined and optimized, it's not in general possible to reconstruct the call stack anyway... At least not without storing significant additional data, and restricting the implementation of optimizations. This would impose a significant run time cost for a feature that it seems few people would need and which is available in a platform dependent way anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As Dan said, no backtrace and no plan to do it, up to my knowledge.
About debugging utilities, besides asserts I only know standard macros inherited from C, like

- __FILE__ to know the name of the current input file,
- __LINE__ to know the current input line number,
- __func__ to know the current function.

For instance

```
    1. #include <iostream>
    2. 
    3. int main() {
    4.   std::cout << "File " << __FILE__ << ", line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    5. }
```

will output

```
    File /path/your_bin, line 4
```

More details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get a pretty good overview of what is going into the next standard by looking at the documents published by the standards committee:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/

There you can find proposals written by various people, meeting minutes, draft standards, and issue lists.

Given the status of C++14, the draft standards is the most informative document for your particular question. Short answer: there's nothing new for debugging in there.

There was a paper about stack traces back in 2012:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3441.html

However, it doesn't seem to have left any traces in the actual standard. If you want to find out more, you could try reading the minutes of the meetings around there, or contact the paper's author - not everything is recorded in the meetings, just the sessions where everyone gets together and votes, but not the work of individual groups.